# Unexpected problem processing bytes for class in Grails with Elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, grails, spring-loaded

I'm trying to get Elasticsearch working in my Grails project. I'm using the Java Rest High-level client in Elasticsearch documented here [`https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.3/java-rest-high-getting-started-maven.html`]. I'm using Elasticsearch 6.3.2 version, Java 8, Grails 2.4.4

I have created a service class and added an import statement at the beginning of the file. For eg: `import org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException`
And, when I start Grails I get the error below. But if I remove that import statement the application runs fine. So, what's happening in the import ?

```
Sep 12, 2018 3:05:29 PM org.springsource.loaded.agent.SpringLoadedPreProcessor preProcess
SEVERE: Unexpected problem transforming call sites
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected problem processing bytes for class
    at org.springsource.loaded.ConstantPoolChecker2.readConstantPool(ConstantPoolChecker2.java:196)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ConstantPoolChecker2.<init>(ConstantPoolChecker2.java:128)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ConstantPoolChecker2.getReferences(ConstantPoolChecker2.java:102)
    at org.springsource.loaded.MethodInvokerRewriter.rewrite(MethodInvokerRewriter.java:300)
    at org.springsource.loaded.MethodInvokerRewriter.rewriteUsingCache(MethodInvokerRewriter.java:156)
    at org.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.methodCallRewriteUseCacheIfAvailable(TypeRegistry.java:828)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Entry: 14 18
    at org.springsource.loaded.ConstantPoolChecker2.processConstantPoolEntry(ConstantPoolChecker2.java:335)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ConstantPoolChecker2.readConstantPool(ConstantPoolChecker2.java:186)
```

So, can someone help me understand what's happening here?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to delete the `.grails` folder in your home folder?

Comment: Yes I did try that. No luck.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error in versions of Java later than Java 7, but was able to get it to work in Java 7